# Why are differential of $\sin^2(x)$ and integral of $\sin(2x)$ not the same?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, derivatives

I was working on a list of common integrals and differentials and I came across this question.

If $${d\over d\theta}(\sin^2\theta) = \sin(2\theta)$$

Then why is $$\int \sin(2\theta) \space d\theta = -\frac12\cos(2\theta) + c$$

Isn't integration the opposite of differentiation?

Comment: there's a trig identity saying $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx} (\sin^2\theta) = \sin(2\theta)\cdot\dfrac{dx}{d\theta}$.  But probably you meant $\dfrac{d}{d\theta}$ instead of $\dfrac{d}{dx}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-\dfrac12 \cos (2\theta)$ is equal to $\sin^2\theta$ up to an arbitrary constant.

Indeed, $-\dfrac12 \cos (2\theta)=-\dfrac12(1-2\sin^2\theta)=\sin^2\theta-\dfrac12$.

Thus, they differ by only $\dfrac12$.

Answer (score 2):

The question is whether
$$
\sin^2\theta = -\frac 1 2 \cos(2\theta) + C.
$$

A standard trigonometric identity, a half-angle formula, says this is true if $C=\dfrac 1 2$.